# Sideloading with Ember ActiveModelAdapter and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ember.js, relationships, activemodel

I have two models:

```
user: [ 
  firstName: DS.attr('string'),
  lastName: DS.attr('string'),
  animals: DS.hasMany('animal', { async: true })
]

animal: [ 
  name: DS.attr('string'),
  user: DS.belongsTo('user', { async: true })
]
```

When I see animals route all works fine, the JSON that rails return is like:

```
{"animals":[{"id":1,"name":"Wiskey","user_id":3}
```

and Ember call a GET for the user/3.

When I try to find all users what I have is this json:

```
{"users":[{"id":3,"firstName":"Bob","lastName":"Marley","animal_ids":[4,8,14]}
```

but no GET was call for the animals 4, 8 and 14.
What is the problem? The adapter that I use is ActiveModelAdapter.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at active model serializer gem ([here](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers)) on how to have rails return users and animals in one call from rails

There is also a very good railscast about it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/409-active-model-serializers)

Answer (score 0):

You must try to access the `animals` relationship for Ember Data to request the additional records.  If it's not being displayed in a template or accessed elsewhere, then there's no need to make the request to the server.

The other reason that it might not be making the request is if another call to the server has already resulted in Ember Data loading those records into the store.  If it has already persisted those records, then it won't try to load them again unless expressly requested to do so.

Comment: Good explanation. From her title, it sounds like she was expecting the `animals` to get "sideloaded" automagically, which did not happen

Comment: Yes, I need to take automatically the data. I not think is a rails problem but a ember problem because when I get Users not start a get for the related Animals. Maybe miss some setting. I have try to serialize data with ActiveModelSerializer in this manner DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend(DS.EmbeddedRecordsMixin, {attrs:{animals: { serialize: 'ids' }}}); but nothing.